# Jquery table manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to exclude the first td on the click event of jquery that I created below?
I want to exclude the all first td of the rows on the click event that produces dialog box.

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr").click(function(){

//some code here

});

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#list td").not(":first-child").click(function(){
```

Though your posted html does not contain `#list`.  I am assuming this exists in the real page.

Comment: my jquery(this) returns nothing.